# HighCharts SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to write a script that produces a col chart. The data is from an MySQL query that produces the following array content:

97.2,63.9,33.4,28.9,325.2,114.9,46.1,56.7,104.9,4.5,42.2,56.4,10.5

When I run the script I get an error:

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

I have tracked down to where I thik the error is but can not see whats wrong.

Inside the jQuery function I have an PHP echo statement which populates the $data variable with the data, `$data[] = $row_An['AValue'];`.

The values are correct as seen in FireFox dev console. Can anyone see why I am getting the error.

```
$(function () {

<?php
$data[] = $row_An['AValue'];
?>

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'AN'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Inbound', 'Outbound', 'InService']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    series: [{
     data: [97.2,63.9,33.4,28.9,325.2,114.9,46.1,56.7,104.9,4.5,42.2,56.4,10.5],
     pointStart: 0,
     pointInterval
  }]
});

});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what's value in pointInterval ? its wrong to leave that without any value.

Comment: Edit: The data variable is $data[] = $row_An['AValue'];

Comment: I have give the pointInterval a value but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

what's value in pointInterval ? its wrong to leave that without any value

```
series: [{
 data: [97.2,63.9,33.4,28.9,325.2,114.9,46.1,56.7,104.9,4.5,42.2,56.4,10.5],
 pointStart: 0,
 pointInterval    //here is error you should provide value or remove it
}]
```

Also, these two properties PointInterval and PointStart are part of plotOptions.series

your number of categories don't match with number of data points ,correct them

```
categories: ['Inbound', 'Outbound', 'InService']
```

Comment: Now given the categories the correct number of values, still the same error

Comment: Plz share a working fiddle with the problem you are having , for php data part: just copy paste the output of php echo in series:data...@DCJones

Comment: I have remove any ref to pointInterval, ths is the best I can do with jsfidder. https://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/xk718zb4/2/

Comment: I updated your fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/xk718zb4/6/ everything is working fine, review the fiddle

Comment: seems like no issue in highcharts part , I suspect your php array declaration has issue    <?php
$data[] = $row_An['AValue'];
?>  Shouldn't it be like           <?php
$data  = $row_An['AValue'];
?>  I am not php guy , but I feel issue in array declaration assignment.